# How to avoid hitting allies with projectiles

Tags: game-physics

I am creating a game and have encountered a problem that I am having hard time finding a solution for. I have tried searching, but all I get is various mathematical equations about projectile trajectories, this is not exactly what I am looking for.
I am looking for explanation or links or better search terms I could use to find information about how to implement non-intantanious projectiles that their travel paths would not hit allied units along the path.

Example problem:
0. Game is in 3D.
1. Entity A has aimed, and confirmed that its target entity B can be hit accountting to things like target velocity and bullet speed.
2. Entity A fires a projectile it will take lets say 1.5 seconds to hit.
3. Random Entity C comes in and goes straight through projectiles path getting hit at 0.8s.

How do I avoid this situation?
Calculate all possible entity and projectile trajectories and account for everything? What if there are alot of entities moving around?
What are the common practices to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hittable entities have a global max speed (i.e. ignoring things like other projectiles, all units or thrown objects may be limited to *X*m/s) then you can use that to generate a "cone" along the flight path (with a hemisphere at the end) to identify which entities you need to check.  This hopefully reduces the number of checks each time an entity aims.

Don't forget to consider overshoot - a thrown entity may be close to the flight path, but without the ability to apply acceleration it could zip past in front of the projectile without getting hit.  You're looking for an upper and lower bound of 'potential' movement.

Comment: Hm it seems going the calculate "everything" is the way to go. By everything I mean having some kind of system that does what you describe and what I was hoping to avoid. But if someone else is saying it's the way it's probably right, I'll have to test and see how much all these calculations will slow down my game... Anyways, thank you.